# How to delete iCloud storage Mail cache?

Tags: icloud, email

I've deleted every E-Mail in my iCloud account. **But the storage overview shows me 2,2GB used space for my Mails.**

[image]

But there is no E-Mail left:
[image]

> How can I update the storage overview or delete the iCloud cache for
>   my Mails?

I just have the free version and 2,2GB takes a lot of my space.

Comment: Did you also empty the Trash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. So for future readers:

Mail is caching (Bug?) the storage space in Mail. So after deleting a few thousands E-Mails, the space is still taken.

**The solution:**

> Insert a few E-Mails back in archive. After importing a few E-Mails
>   again, Apple is updating the cache.

**Guide:**

> 1. Deleting every E-Mail in archive
> 2. Spotting that the space is still taken
> 3. Insert 3-4 E-Mails back to archive
> 4. Waiting until the space is updated (look at iCloud.com)
> 5. Deleting the 3-4 E-Mails in archive