# Why does iCloud use storage even when i have deleted all my backups?

Tags: icloud, backup

I had 3 devices but now I have removed all. There are no photos synced, no keynotes or any documents saved.. but if you see the screenshot my iCloud drive says i am using 1.09GB ++ of data.

[image]

No idea what is using that and how do I clean my iCloud drive?

Also if I go to iCloud.com it says it has 1.09GB of backup. What backup is it talking about?

[image]

Please help.

Update: So i did manage storage in my icloud setting in mac and this is what it shows..

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So had a call with apple customer care as i want to get to the root cause and they have finally resolved this issue. They found out that somehow i had my old ipad backup on the icloud and it won't show up to me. They are able to see with the tools they are using. May be some bug. They escalated to senior apple experts. The senior expert called and said they will try to delete the redundant backup, called me again and told to sign out of icloud and sign in. And it was done.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like [the same problem](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/178189/how-to-delete-icloud-storage-mail-cache) I've encountered. What helped me was:

> 1. Create a backup again
> 2. Wait until the storage space is updated
> 3. Delete the backup

The solution for me was to update the "cache". Somehow when you are deleting to many things at the same time, iCloud isn't updating the storage.

Comment: No thats not working for me.. I tried several stuffs for last few days. Did new backups, deleted everything, re do backups.. somehow that space won't be given back to me.. so weird.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if iCloud backup is enabled on your device, open the Settings app, select iCloud, then select Storage & Backup.